# Refresh BackgroundQuery VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub OPInport(month As Integer, year As Integer)
'
' Macro6 Macro
'F und G

'
    Dim selectedRange As Date
    Dim WrkBook As Workbook
    Dim WrkSheet As Worksheet
    Set WrkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set WrkSheet = ActiveSheet

selectedRange = DateSerial(year, month, 1)
MsgBox selectedRange

WrkBook.Sheets(1).Columns("G:H").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"

Range("$A$1").Value = "Change"

Application.CutCopyMode = False
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "ODBC;DSN=OpsApps;UID=Alligatoah;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2016;WSID=AT000616;DATABASE=OpsApps" _
    , Destination:=Range("$B$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT IPM_V_TV_URB.Customer, IPM_V_TV_URB.KNUM, IPM_V_TV_URB.DMRF, IPM_V_TV_URB.HeaderBoM, IPM_V_TV_URB.ProgramReleasedCosts, IPM_V_TV_URB.PlnLaunch, IPM_V_TV_URB.SystemSDate, IPM_V_TV" _
    , _
    "_URB.ActualCosts" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM OpsApps.dbo.IPM_V_TV_URB IPM_V_TV_URB" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (IPM_V_TV_URB.SystemSDate>={ts selectedRange & 00:00:00'})" _ 
    )
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_OpsApps"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

I want to select a specific range of data, but when i try to do that it says "Runtime Error 1004 General ODBC Error" and points out the last line, .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False. Im quite new to VBA and cant really find a solution to the problem. It only started showing that error message when i changed the date in the where question with selectedDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the selected date into your string - what you are doing currently is using the literal name of the variable as a date.

```
"_URB.ActualCosts" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM OpsApps.dbo.IPM_V_TV_URB IPM_V_TV_URB" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (IPM_V_TV_URB.SystemSDate>={ts '" & Format(selectedRange, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " 00:00:00'})"
```

You may need to change the date format used.

Comment: there seems to be a problem at the end at the 00:00:00 part right before it starts

Comment: okey found tha problem 
but still have the problem with .refresh BackgroundQuery

Comment: I've amended the code as there was also an apostrophe missing.